# AngularJS handle stacked promisses

Tags: angularjs, ionic-framework, promise, angular-promise

I have an array of arrays that I want to run a async. function on.

```
for(var a in As){

    this.doSomething(a).then(function(result){
        for(var b in Bs){
            this.somthingElse(b).then(function(){console.log(result)});
        }                   
    })
}
```

How can I force this to be processed in synchronously? I found `Array.prototype.map` and `Array.prototype.reduce`, but they seem not to be available in AngularJS?

Comment: Why synchronously? What exactly are you trying to do?

Comment: In something else I am pushing data to a DB server. I want to avoid any concurrency conflicts through async promises.

Answer (score 2):

Firstly, while AngularJS does not include a `angular.map` or `angular.reduce`, `Array.prototype.map` and `Array.prototype.reduce` is largely unrelated to AngularJS.

Any modern browser would support the `map` and `reduce` array functions. `angular.forEach` is for compatibility purposes (for IE8 and earlier). If you want to use map/reduce and supporting IE8 or earlier, try [underscore.js](http://underscorejs.org/) or [lodash](https://lodash.com/).

Back to your question, there is not enough information on what you want to achieve and what actually the variables `As` and `Bs` are.

Let's make the following assumptions:

1. `As` and `Bs` are both proper JavaScript Arrays
2. For every memeber of `As`, you want to `doSomething` with it, wait until it's done, then do `somthingElse` with every member from `Bs`, when that's done, log the result of `doSomething`

   - This means you'll run `somthingElse` `As.length * Bs.length` times.
3. You do not care which `As` member has to be done first

   - This means `As` members would *concurrently* be done together
4. Similarly, for every `Bs` iteration, you do not care who is done first

Below is the code, you will need Angular's `$q` service:

```
// We cannot bring 'this' into map function's scope, so assign it to 'self'
var self = this;
var promises = As.map(function(a){
    return self.doSomething(a).then(function(resultOfA){
        return $q.all(Bs.map(function(b){
            return self.somthingElse(b).then(function(resultOfB){
                console.log(resultOfA);
                return resultOfB; // Not neccessary
            });
        }))
    });
});

// Now if you want to do something after all those iterations, do it here:
$q.all(promises).then(function(){
    // do something after all 'As.length * Bs.length' iterations are done
});
```

You will see in the console log random sequences of `resultOfA`, implying they are done asynchronously. If you want get the actual results for use later, you can do this instead:

```
// We cannot bring 'this' into map function's scope, so assign it to 'self'
var self = this;
var promises = As.map(function(a){
    return self.doSomething(a).then(function(resultOfA){
        return $q.all(Bs.map(self.somthingElse)).then(function(resultsOfB){
            return {
                resultOfA: resultOfA,
                resultsOfB: resultsOfB
            };
        });
    })
});

// Now if you want to do something after all those iterations, do it here:
$q.all(promises).then(function(resultsOfA){
    // do something after all 'As.length * Bs.length' iterations are done
    console.log(resultsOfA);
    // Output would be something like:
    // [{
    //   resultOfA: 'Result of A[0]',
    //   resultsOfB: ['Result of B[0]', 'Result of B[1]', 'Result of B[2]...']
    // }, {
    //   resultOfA: 'Result of A[1]',
    //   resultsOfB: ['Result of B[0]', 'Result of B[1]', 'Result of B[2]...']
    // }]
});
```

Answer (score 1):

you can create an array of promises and then use $q.all() to resolve all promises when they are all completed.

```js
var promises = [];
for(var a in As){
  promises.push(this.doSomething(a));
}

$q.all(promises).then(function(result){
  for(var b in Bs){
    this.somthingElse(b).then(function(){console.log(result)});
  }                   
})
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you're looking for a way to run everything synchronously - so if you have the following:

```
var As = ['A1', 'A2', 'A3'];
var Bs = ['B1', 'B2', 'B3'];
```

You'd want the execution to be 'A1', 'B1', 'B2', 'B3', 'A2', 'B1', ...

Is that correct?

If so, the following could be used:

```
function start(){
  $log.log('start');
  As.reduce(function(promise, itemA){
    return promise.then(function(){
      return doSomething(itemA).then(startBs);
    });
  }, $q.resolve());
}

function startBs(){
  $log.log('start Bs');
  return Bs.reduce(function(promise, itemB){
    return promise.then(function(){
      return somethingElse(itemB);
    });
  }, $q.resolve());
}
```

Sample plunker: https://plnkr.co/edit/fgiI3J2ylcW4FUXuXjIP?p=preview

Comment: Your assumptions are correct, probably to be more specific : A1, A1.B1, A1.B2, A1.B3 , A2, A2.B1,A2.B2,A2.B3 ... where each A has a different B list

Answer (score 0):

if you are ok using [bluebird](https://github.com/petkaantonov/bluebird), you can do something like this:

```
function doSomething(v){
    return new Promise(function(fullfil, reject){
      setTimeout(function(){
       console.log(v);
       fullfil(v);
      },500);
    });
};
 var As = [[1,2],[3,4],[5,6]];
(function start(){
  return Promise.map(As, function(a) {
        return doSomething(a).then(function(){
      return Promise.map(a, function(b) {
                    return doSomething(b);
    });
    });
});
})();
```